# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.How to fix this error?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[Traceback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y9Ht.png)import tkinter
import PIL
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk;

## from ttk import *

from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Root(Tk):
    def **init**(self):
        super(Root, self).**init**()
        self.title("Brain Tumor Detection Using Deep learning")
        self.minsize(400, 200)
       # self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

```
    self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Choose Here")
    self.labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 5, padx = 150, pady = 150)
    self.button()



def button(self):
    self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse A File",command=self.open_img)
    self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)



def fileDialog(self):

    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
    (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")) )
    print(self.filename)
    #print(self.filename)
    #photo = PhotoImage(self.filename)

    self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
    self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    self.label.configure(text = self.filename)
```

``def open_img(self): 
    # Select the Imagename from a folder 
        x = self.fileDialog()
       # print(x)
    # opens the image 
        img = Image.open(x)

```
# resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter 
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS) 

# PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc 
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    #imgs = Label(self, image=img)
    #imgs.image = img
# create a label 
    panel = Label(root, image = img) 

# set the image as img 
    panel.image = img 
    panel.grid(row = 2)
```

Comment: All of your post is code.Please use the right format and give us the traceback.

Comment: Somewhere in there is a “x.read”, where x is None - identify where, then back to identity the why.